# Reference Request: Jimbo's Proof of Quantum Schur-Weyl Duality

Tags: reference-request, quantum-groups, hecke-algebras

In his seminal 1986 paper "A $q$-analogue of $U(\mathfrak{gl}(N+1))$, Hecke Algebra, and the Yang-Baxter Equation", Jimbo asserted (Proposition 3) that the quantum group associated to $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ and the Hecke algebra associated to $S_n$ are in Schur-Weyl duality. But the paper doesn't have the proofs, and Jimbo says in the introduction "Details will appear elsewhere".

Did the details ever actually appear? I haven't been able to find them anywhere, or even a citation to a longer paper.

I'm interested for curiosity's sake in Jimbo's original proof, but more broadly, I mostly just want a (hopefully clear) full proof of this result. Every source I've found either sketches the proof or does it for a related case.

Comment: Well, at least *a* reference: Chari, Pressley, *A guide to quantum groups*, see Sect 10.2, esp Thm 10.2.5 (i), Prop 10.2.6 and the bibliographical notes on p337. I'm not sure if it meets your criteria, but it's at least a start. See also the references at https://mathoverflow.net/q/15392.

Comment: Thanks! Chari and Pressley is a great source, but as far as I can tell, doesn't give a proof. Am I missing something? I'm going to take a look as some of the links in the other post though!

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. The idea is that the $\check{R}$-matrix, i.e. the permutation times the R-matrix, coincides (possibly up to a factor: $\epsilon$ for eq (20) on p335 of Chari--Pressley) with the Hecke generator. The 'RTT relation', i.e. R intertwines the ordinary and opposite coproducts, thus implies that the Hecke-algebra action commutes with the representation of $U_q(\mathfrak{gl}_N)$ (which is defined via the repeated coproduct).

Comment: ...There's a subtlety though: that representation of the Hecke algebra is not faithful, but factors through a representation of the Temperley--Lieb algebra. This is worked out in detail in e.g. the BSc thesis of Weelinck, *Representation Theory of the Temperley--Lieb algebra and its connections with the Hecke algebra* (UvA, 2012)